# Concurrent writes to MySQL and testing solutions

Tags: mysql, transactions

I was practicing some "system design" coding questions and I was interested in how to solve a concurrency problem in MySQL. The problem was "design an inventory checkout system".

Let's say you are trying to check out a specific item from an inventory, a library book for instance.

If two people are on the website, looking to book it, is it possible that they both check it out? Let's assume the query is updating the status of the row to mark a boolean `checked_out` to `True`.

Would transactions solve this issue? It would cause the second query that runs to fail (assuming they are the same query).

Alternatively, we insert rows into a `checkouts` table. Since both queries read that the item is not checked out currently, they could both insert into the table. I don't think a transaction would solve this, unless the transaction includes reading the table to see if a checkout currently exists for this item that hasn't yet ended.

One of the suggested methods

How would I simulate two writes at the exact same time to test this?

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch01.html

Comment: Two writes cannot actually occur at the same time. You could construct your update query so that it checks the value of checked_out as part of the update. If true, it would fail, letting your code know which write attempt failed. A better approach might be to have a column with the key of the user checking out the book. If it's "not me", the update would fail, and you could also see who checked the book out.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Appreciate the pointers to resources. Do you have advice on how to test such a situation in a deterministic way?

Comment: @VishaalKalwani just open two mysql cli connections start a transaction in both of them, issue an update in the first one, but do not commit. Then issue the same update in the 2nd one - and you will see that the update in the 2nd will block due to the exclusive lock set by the first transaction.

Answer (score 3):

No, transactions alone do not address concurrency issues. Let's quickly revisit [mysql's definition of transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_transaction):

> Transactions are atomic units of work that can be committed or rolled back. When a transaction makes multiple changes to the database, either all the changes succeed when the transaction is committed, or all the changes are undone when the transaction is rolled back.

To sum it up: transactions are a way to ensure data integrity.

RDBMSs use various types of [locking](http://The%20system%20of%20protecting%20a%20transaction%20from%20seeing%20or%20changing%20data%20that%20is%20being%20queried%20or%20changed%20by%20other%20transactions.%20The%20locking%20strategy%20must%20balance%20reliability%20and%20consistency%20of%20database%20operations%20(the%20principles%20of%20the%20ACID%20philosophy)%20against%20the%20performance%20needed%20for%20good%20concurrency.%20Fine-tuning%20the%20locking%20strategy%20often%20involves%20choosing%20an%20isolation%20level%20and%20ensuring%20all%20your%20database%20operations%20are%20safe%20and%20reliable%20for%20that%20isolation%20level.), [isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level), and [storage engine level solutions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html) to address concurrency. People often mistake transactions as a mean to control concurrency because transactions affect how long **certain** locks are held.

Focusing on InnoDB: when you issue an `update` statement, mysql places an [exclusive lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_exclusive_lock) on the record being updated. Only the transaction holding the exclusive lock can modify the given record, the others have to wait until the transaction is committed.

How does this help you preventing multiple users checking out the same book? Let's say you have an `id` field uniquely identifying the books and a `checked_out` field indicating the status of the book.

You can use the following atomic `update` to check out a book:

```
update books set checked_out=1 where id=xxx and checked_out=0
```

The `checked_out=0` criteria makes sure that the `update` only succeeds if the book is not checked out yet. So, if the above statement affects a row, then the current user checks out the book. If it does not affect any rows, then someone else has already checked out the book. The exclusive lock makes sure that only one transaction can update the record at any given time, thus serializing the access to that record.

If you want to use a separate `checkouts` table for reserving books, then you can use a unique index on book ids to prevent the same book being checked out more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions don't cause updates to fail. They cause sequences of queries to be serialized. Only one accessor can run the sequence of queries; others wait.

Everything in SQL is a transaction, single-statement update operations included. The kind of transaction denoted by `BEGIN TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` bundles a series of queries together.

> I don't think a transaction would solve this, unless the transaction
>   includes reading the table to see if a checkout currently exists for
>   this item.

That's generally correct. Checkout schemes must *always* read availability from the database. The purpose of the transaction is to avoid race conditions when multiple users attempt to check out the same item.

SQL doesn't have thread-safe atomic test-and-set instructions like multithreaded processor cores have. So you need to use transactions for this kind of thing.

The simplest form of checkout uses a transaction, something like this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT is_item_available, id FROM item WHERE catalog_number = whatever FOR UPDATE;
/* if the item is not available, tell the user and commit the transaction without update*/
UPDATE item SET is_item_available = 0 WHERE id = itemIdPreviouslySelected;
/* tell the user the checkout succeeded. */
COMMIT;
```

It's clearly possible for two or more users to attempt to check out the same item more-or-less simultaneously. But only one of them actually gets the item.

A more complex checkout scheme, not detailed here, uses a two-step system. First step: a  transaction to reserve the item for a user, rejecting the reservation if someone else has it checked out or reserved.  Second step: reservation holder has a fixed amount of time to accept the reservation and check out the item, or the reservation expires and some other user may reserve the item.

Comment: I don't see how your code prevents both users to read the exactly same value and then update it. AFAIK you need to lock the row with `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you're right. Thanks for the reminder. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The situation I was thinking of is 2 users reading the same database and seeing that the item was free, and then both attempting to check it out, similar to interleaving threads in concurrent programming. Transactions make it so they read the state and check it out all in one go, which prevents the race condition. With the scheme you mentioned at the end, we can now make it "asynchronous" which is a better experience for users.

Comment: There are some fundamental flaws in this answer. 1. Transactions are not suitable for concurrency control. Transactions ensure that all statements in a set of statements are completely executed and all modifications are committed or none of the changes happen. Concurrency control is done via locks. The transactions only influence how long certain locks are held. 2. SQL does have atomic, thread-safe data modification statements. For example, you do not need the `select ... for update`, it is enough to do `UPDATE item SET is_item_available = 0 WHERE catalog_number = x and is_item_available = 1`

Comment: If the update affects a row, then the current customer gets the book. If the update does not affect any rows, then another user has already checked the book out. Exclusive row locks ensure that only one update is executed at a time.